# Working with a simple javascript/jQuery UI element

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have no experience working with jQuery or Javascript, so I am picking this up on the file. I have to put a slider in an .ASCX page. This is part of the code in that .ascx file:

```
<tr>
    <td style="width: 140px; height: 25px;"><asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server" CssClass="InputHeader" meta:resourcekey="lblHeader" /></td>
    <td><asp:Label ID="lblSliderLeft" runat="server" Text="L" CssClass="sliderLabelLeft" />
        <input type="range" name="slider1" id="slider1" style="width:210px" value="1" min="0" max="1" step="1" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblSliderRight" runat="server" Text="R" CssClass="sliderLabelRight" />
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

At the top of the page, I have included this:

```
<!-- Load jQuery and jQuery UI -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- Load the jQuery UI CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
</body>
```

Now my question is, how do I do stuff with this slider? How would I set its value from a function in my .cs file? How do I grab its value in the .cs file?

Comment: is there any console error?

Comment: Using the dev tools on IE, when i go to the page, no error on the console.

Comment: @Tesla After your comment, the slider, is it not working on IE only or other browsers as well?

Comment: It seems ok in [_JSFiddle_](http://jsfiddle.net/manassornpn/oqLbLn1s/)

Comment: Okay. I updated the question. I went a different approach and got it to show up. Now my question is a basic javascript one. How do I work with this slider?

Comment: What do you mean _"work with this slider"_? @Tesla

Comment: I do not have any experience with Javascript, so I am confused as to how to work with this control. For example, how would I set its value based on data in my .cs file? How would I grab its value from my .cs file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a JSfiddle that may answer your question.

http://jsfiddle.net/oqLbLn1s/6/

```
<tr>
    <td style="width: 140px; height: 25px;"><asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server" CssClass="InputHeader" meta:resourcekey="lblHeader" /></td>
    <td><asp:Label ID="lblLeft" runat="server" Text="L" CssClass="sliderLabelLeft" />
        <div id="slider" style="margin-top:100px;"></div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblRight" runat="server" Text="R" CssClass="sliderLabelRight" />
    </td>
    <td><div id="amount" style="padding: 10px; border: 3px solid silver; text-align:center;">50</div></td>
</tr>



// When the browser is ready...
$(function () {
    // Create a new jQuery UI Slider element
    // and set some default parameters.
    $("#slider").slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 50,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            // While sliding, update the value in the #amount div element
            var value = $("#slider").slider("value"); // You can use value anywhere
            $("#amount").text(value);
            $("#amount").css("font-size", value);
        }
    });
    value = $("#slider").slider("value");
    $("#amount").text(value);
    $("#amount").css("font-size", value);
});
```